# series summation of quadratic exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

I need to prove the equation
$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} An^2+iBn} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{A}} \sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2A}(B-2\pi l)^2}$, where A and B are constants(possibly can be complex number).
First I tried to use the direct expansion $e^x=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, but it is quite hard to using binomial expansion and summarizing them. The second one I tried is the discrete fourier transform, but in wikipedia, there are only finite sum case, where I want to do is infinite sum. In fact, I can't understand why the coefficient $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{A}}$ appears. How can I prove this?

Comment: [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Comment: Wow. I didn't expected there is such wonderful formula. Thanks for help!